# Is there a tool similar to IEpxress or 7Zip that can pass command line arguments to a dependency

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, 7-zip

I recently discovered IExpress and would like to use it to package arbitrary scripts in any language with their respective interpreters/libraries/dependencies. IExpress and 7zip can offer all of that (along with a handful of other tools). However, I don't see a way to be able to pass the command line arguments which get passed to the resulting self-extracting exe through to the batch file that gets extracted when running it.

Is there a tool that offers this? Or some other method I could use to achieve this?

Example:

run.bat

app.exe

app.dll

I would package these three files to get self extracted when running an exe called "Final.exe" which would call 'cmd /c run.bat' which would run app.exe which depends on app.dll. However, how would I be able to pass command line arguments to Final.exe and have them pass through to run.bat?

Comment: Find an installer creator that allows you to do this, or code your own. If you simply want recommendations then this question is off-topic and belongs on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adcae113-4758-481a-a367-60d5d14d97d6/this-is-how-to-turn-vbs-and-js-files-into-exe-files-from-the-command-line-without-third-party-tools?forum=scripting

Shows how to host vbs scripts in an exe made with notepad and a compiler built into windows.

You'll have to know some programming to adapt this to your needs.